# Изменение цвета Овала

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть круг, код:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="EllipseBackgound" Fill="#FF282E33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="94" Margin="384,22,0,0" Stroke="#FF282E33" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" StrokeThickness="0"/>
```

Он без рамки, и нужно изменить его цвет с помощью анимации в C# коде.

Однако это не работает:

```
ColorAnimation a0 = new ColorAnimation(Color.FromRgb(0, 150, 135), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
EllipseBackgound.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, a0);
```

Я не нашел в `Ellipse.СВОЙСТВО` того свойства, через которое можно изменять цвет заливки, а `FillProperty` только для чтения

---

Почему и как сделать так, что бы это работало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня работает так:

```
ColorAnimation a0 = new ColorAnimation(Color.FromRgb(0, 150, 135), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var brush = EllipseBackgound.Fill;
brush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, a0);
```

---

Дело в том, что вам нужно анимировать не кисть (`Brush`), которая является заполнением фона вашей фигуры, а цвет этой кисти. Соответственно и анимацию надо запускать у кисти, а не у эллипса.